# how does django channels knows that a client has disconnected?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I fear that a client loses connection abruptly and get disconnected without leaving any info to the backend. If this happens, will the socket keep active?

Comment: iirc it uses "keep alive messages". If the client does not respond, eventually the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in a issue on the django channels repository:

> - Using websocket auto-ping to periodically assert clients are still connected to sockets, and cutting them loose if not. This is a feature that's already in daphne master if you want to try it, and which is coming in the next release; the ping interval and time-till-considered-dead are both configurable. This solves the (more common) clients-disconnecting-uncleanly issue.
> - Storing the timestamp of the last seen action from a client in a database, and then pruning ones you haven't heard of in a while. This is the only approach that will also get round disconnect not being sent because a Daphne server was killed, but it's more specialised, so Channels can't implement it directly.

[Link to the issue on github](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/293)